# Adding label to D3 path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label

I know how to add text element to simple node (append text). The problem is when I would like to add text to path surrounding several nodes. I have created example on http://jsfiddle.net/FEM3e/5/ Please ignore nodes in upper left corner. So I have two groups of nodes. And I would like to add text for each group. Printscreen of desired output http://dopisna.bencin.si/screenshot.png.

I set path in

```
force.on("tick", function () {
        node.attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
        vis.selectAll("path")
            .data(groups)
            .attr("d", singlePath)
            .enter().insert("path", "g")
            .style("fill", groupFill)
            .style("stroke", groupFill)
            .style("stroke-width", 57)
            .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .style("opacity", .7);
    });
```

I have tried appending text with no success. I am asking for some hints.

Comment: so you've tried `append("text").text(function (d) { return d.something; })` ?

Comment: Yes. I think that the problem is that this path is not node... So it does append text to my <path> element but it's not shown like it's shown when I append it to <g> (node) element.

Comment: Ah, maybe some [W3 Recommendations then](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextOnAPath) and of course [Mike](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3151228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK then.  The problem is that you're using text instead of textPath.  I've modified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FEM3e/7/) and now there's some text, albeit some rather ugly text, appended to your path.

The only real change I've made is the addition of this snippet:

```
        vis.selectAll("text")
            .data(groups)
            .enter()
        .append("text")
            .attr("x", 8)
            .attr("dy", 28)
           .append("textPath")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d,i) { return "#path_" + i; })
        .text(function (d,i) { return "path_" + i; });
```

You can see that you go through the usual selection and data binding.  You then append your text with the attributes you want (definitely change the ones I borrowed from Mikes Bl.ock) and then you append the text path linking it to a path element in the xlink:href attribute. Obviously you then create some text.  One of the cool things about textPath is that it allows you append curved paths.

I think that there's a bit of overkill using the groups as data for the textPath, so you might want to select a more appropriate data selection to bind to this.